# Why is the type of the following function t -> (t -> t1) -> t1

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

```
rev a b = b a
```

I just don't get it, why does this function have the `t -> (t -> t1) -> t1` type?

Comment: What type would you have expected?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`b a` is the application of the function `b` to the argument `a`. That is all the compiler can deduce about what `a` and `b` are, so it assigns names `t` and `t1` to the type of the argument of that function and to the return type of that function and says that `rev` takes an argument and a function that takes that argument and returns the result of the application.

Answer (score 1):

start with the right side: you apply `a` to `b` - so `b` needs to be a function (it **has** to have some type `a -> b`) type (let's call it `b :: t -> t1`) and `a` has to be compatible with this - meaning `a :: t`

no the resulting type if obviously `b`'s codomain (`t1` here)